# Expected Expression with square roots

Tags: c

```
#define PI = 3.141593
#define G = 6.67259E-11
#define g = 9.80665
#define M = 5.972E+24
#define r = 6378000
#define h = 220

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(void)
{
    int value;
    value =sqrt((G/M)/(r+h))

    printf("This is the tangential speed:") value;
    return 0;
}
```

I am very new to coding, and my program is giving me several errors in code blocks, can anyone give me some guidance?

Comment: Drop the `=`  , Use `#define PI  3.141593`.  Tip: best to include the exact error message in the question.

Comment: Ahhh that got rid of most of my errors. There is still one saying "expected ';' before 'printf'

Comment: " "expected ';' before 'printf' –" --> Look at the end of `value =sqrt((G/M)/(r+h))`

Comment: C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\world.cpp: In function 'int main()':
C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\world.cpp:15:50: error: expected ';' before 'value'
     printf("This is the tangential speed: %g\n") value;
                                                  ^
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))

Answer (score 6):

Remove the `=` from all the `#define` statements. They are preprocessor macro definitions, not assignment statements, and they do not use equal signs.

Change `int value` to `double value`, to use floating-point instead of integers.

Add a `;` after `value =sqrt((G/M)/(r+h))`. Statements in C generally end with a semicolon.

Change `printf("This is the tangential speed:") value;` to `printf("This is the tangential speed:  %g.\n", value);`. `printf` is a function call, not a statement, so you pass everything it needs inside a set of parentheses. The string is a format string; it contains both literal text you want printed and conversion specifications like `%g` that tell it to convert an argument to a string. `%g` tells it to convert a `double` argument to a general floating-point display form.

Comment: This is perfect, that makes much more sense. Well put, thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 3):

I see two problems:

1. Smallest problem, but might be significant, is that I assume you want value to be a float or double instead of an int, thus replace

   int value;

by

```
 float value;
```

2. The print statement is incorrect:

   printf("This is the tangential speed:") value;

Assuming value is a float, change it to

```
 printf("This is the tangential speed: %f\n", value);
```

\n makes a new line.

And of course don't forget the remark by chux.